# WP_mail() Issue. Duplicate emails if $_GET['A'] == email

Tags: hooks, wp-mail, init, smtp

I have been scratching my head since last few hours. But still not able to find the cause of the issue.

I have created a `wp_mail()` function which is as follows:

```
if( !empty( $_GET['A'] ) && !empty( $_GET['B'] ) ) { 
 add_action('init', 'test_function', 0 );
  if( !function_exists ('test_function') ){
    function test_function(){

    $to = 'dummyemail@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Email Subject';

    $body = 'This is some body text .... ';

    $header = 'From: Test <support@test-domain.com>';

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $header  );

    }
  }
}
```

The function runs fine as far as both the `GET` parameters are non-email values. But as soon as I set any of those as an email. The mail function starts sending email twice.

So in short:

**This one works fine:**

`$_GET['A']` or `$_GET['B']` = any string (non-email). (Email is fine)

mydomain.com/?A=true&B=false

**But this one does not:**

`$_GET['A']` or `$_GET['B']` = testemail@gmail.com. (Emails get twice)

mydomain.com/?A=true&B=testemail@gmail.com

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The above script runs fine on my system. Please check maybe your page is reloading after running this script

Comment: Did you try to set one variable as email?

Comment: i tried www.domain.com/?A=abcd&B=test@xyz.com. I only recieved one email.

Comment: One thing I noticed. I had `if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) { die; }` at the top of my file. Could this be the cause? I just replaced it with `if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {exit; }` and the issue seems to gone. Another thing is that if I am logged in to wp-admin, it sends two emails. If I am logged out, then only one.